# How to order various layers on map

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have 4-5 layers on top of map. How to order them so that I can decide which one comes first, second and last.Right now, I only know bringToFront and bringToBack.Is there any way I can order all 5 of them as I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tile Layers** can be specified a [`zIndex` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-zindex) ([MapBox reference](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.3/l-tilelayer/)) to order them one each other. However this `zIndex` is automatically changed if you use `bringToFront()` or `bringToBack()` method(s). They are all part of the [`tilePane`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panes), the bottom-most pane in the map.

**Image overlays** do not have `zIndex` option. You have to use `bringToFront()` and `bringToBack()` to order them one each other, or to add them to map in the desired order. They are part of the `overlayPane`, which is just above the `tilePane`.

**Vector shapes layers** cannot be ordered through `zIndex` either. You have to use `bringToFront()` and `bringToBack()`, or to add them to map in the desired order. All vector shapes are contained in a single SVG (or Canvas) element, which is part of the `overlayPane`. So you can have all shapes in a certain position compared to Image Overlays. But you cannot have some shapes below and some above an Image Overlay.

Just for the sake of completeness:

- Markers are part of the `markerPane`, which is above `overlayPane`. They are automatically ordered so that top markers (i.e. Northern) are below bottom ones (i.e. Southern).
- Markers' shadows are part of the `shadowPane`, which is actually between the `overlayPane` and the `markerPane`.
- Popups are part of the `popupPane`, which is on top of `markerPane`.

You can even re-arrange the order of panes through CSS.

Comment: Can I make new panes and add some of the layers in those panes and reorder? How to order panes through css? could you please give an example

Comment: Panes number and usage are hard-coded in Leaflet 0.x and current MapBox unfortunately. But if you can switch to Leaflet 1.0 (currently in beta), you can create your own panes (with `z-index` in CSS through `className`) and specify into which ones your layers should go.